# How can I draw diagrams using Google Web Toolkit?

Tags: gwt, diagram, diagramming

I am considering solutions for drawing diagrams using Google Web Toolkit (GWT).
Up until now I have found only the [gwt-diagrams](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-diagrams/) project but it seems abandoned.

Are there any suggestions about diagramming with GWT?

Comment: It would be awesome if a tool like this existed. Unfortunately, until HTML5 become a standard and become integrated in all major browser, I doubt this will exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm also looking into this, for drawing family trees. I'm currently prototyping with [gwt-graphics](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-graphics/), which looks to be actively developed and is nearing version 1.0.

There is also the [Raphael javascript library](http://raphaeljs.com/), and a couple of thorough blog posts about wrapping GWT around them [here](http://googlewebtoolkit.blogspot.com/2009/09/hydro4ge-paas-built-with-gwt.html) and [here](http://www.filsa.net/2010/02/28/continuing-adventures-with-gwt/). The guys in the first article actually released their code for as [raphaelgwt](http://code.google.com/p/raphaelgwt/).

I can't comment on any of the raphael stuff yet since I haven't used it, I just found this in my own research for drawing components.

Comment: I'm also looking into drawing family trees. Just out of interest, what did you end up using?

Comment: I ended up using the Raphael-GWT library. Simple and works great.

Answer (score 1):

You can use draw2d and gef(eclipse Graphical Editing Framework) to develop your GWT Diagram App Now.
look at this: http://code.google.com/p/trufun-webrcp/
the GWT framework with completely open source based on html5 technology, is used to transplant eclipse RCP to GWT WEB.

Answer (score 0):

I would use Google Chart Tools: http://code.google.com/apis/charttools/

Comment: Thank you, but I am looking for an api to draw organizational charts, shapes and connections between them. From what I saw charttools cant do what I want.

Comment: You might be able to use the experimental GraphViz functionality to make an org chart. http://code.google.com/apis/chart/docs/gallery/graphviz.html

Answer (score 0):

I am actually working on a GWT library to draw diagrams and add widgets on the connections. Here is the project site http://code.google.com/p/gwt-links, you'll find a demo site and a video demonstration.