# GWT (Graph) Diagram Frameworks?

Tags: gwt, diagrams, bpmn

I'm looking for a framework for GWT to visualize graphs such as workflow/process diagrams (ideally BPMN capabilites) with a useable auto-layouter and nice shapes. GraphViz has a good layouter but the shapes are not very nice (except you implement your owns).

Unfortunatelly GWT-Diagram seems to be abandoned.

Cheers!

Jack

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope I'm wrong, but I suspect you're out of luck. Decent diagramming frameworks are rare as hens' teeth. You might have some luck with mxgraph (from [jgraph](http://www.jgraph.com/)), but according to [this question over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2948823/how-can-i-draw-diagrams-using-google-web-toolkit) I suspect that's the best available. [GWT-Links](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-links/) looks alive, but *very* young.

Answer (score 6):

At [jgraph](http://www.jgraph.com) you can find a mxGraph library which is a JavaScript based diagramming framework. A GWT version of it is in development. For a hint about it's capabilities you can go to [Diagram.ly](http://www.diagram.ly). The GWT version will be just as powerful.

Disclaimer :
I am a developer associated with JGraph and I'm currently working on creating a GWT versions of Diagram.ly and mxGraph.

**Update**

We have setup a github repo. You can checkout our latest source from [here](https://github.com/jgraph/mxgraph-gwt).

Comment: Why was the gwt wrapper for mxGraph abandoned?

Comment: @SSR Because it wasn't commercially viable. The level of interest in this GWT wrapper in 2013 is roughly an order of magnitude below what it was in 2011, every serious project just uses JS directly now.

Comment: @David Can it not be open sourced for GWT Community members to update and maintain? We currently have licensed version of mxGraph and are currently maintaining a (as is required) thin GWT wrapper which we cannot share because of mxGraph licensing issues. It is hard to update it and kept it in sync across mxgraph fast release cycle.

Comment: @SSR No, because mxGraph itself isn't open source, that makes it pointless. Please contact us directly rather than have a conversation in comments, it pollutes the thread.

Answer (score 1):

You can use draw2d and gef(eclipse Graphical Editing Framework) to develop your GWT Diagram App Now.
look at this: http://code.google.com/p/trufun-webrcp/
the GWT framework with completely open source based on html5 technology, is used to transplant eclipse RCP to GWT WEB.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at oryx-editor this is what Jboss uses for its web based workflow editor (Guvnor).

http://code.google.com/p/oryx-editor/

Hope this sparks some ideas.